# Format XML data to display on a gridview

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am trying to format XML data to display on a grid.

Page1.aspx. This inserts XML data  stored a xmldatatype:

```
WorkHistory workhis = js.Deserialize<WorkHistory>(json);
XmlDocument work = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");                
objBLL.insert_XMLWork(work, Convert.ToInt64(ui.id));
```

Page2.aspx retrieves it and display on a grid:

```
DataTable FBWorkDt = objBLL.get_FacebookWork(FacebookUserId);
GrdWork.DataSource = FBWorkDt;
GrdWorkPub.DataBind();        
get_FacebookWork(select workinfo from Fprofiles where Userid = FacebookUserId)
```

returns a DataTable

It displays in this format exactly.

```
WorkInfo
<root><work><employer><id>208571635850052</id><name>Netizen Apps</name></employer></work><id>1076483621</id></root>
```

How do I make a normal display instead of XML format?

Thanks
Sun

Comment: By normal, do you mean a normal indented XML format, or a tabular format (which is what GridView is designed for)?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, I mean the tabular format designed for a gridview

Comment: np.  See my answer below - it might not be an exact fit, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a good deal on the shape of the DataTable you're returning, but assuming you want the display to be something like this:

`ID                       Name

--------------------     ---------------------

208571635850052          Netizen Apps`

You could use LINQ:

```
DataTable FBWorkDt = objBLL.get_FacebookWork(FacebookUserId);
var query = from x in FBWorkDt.AsEnumerable()
            select new {
                    id = x.ID,
                    name = x.Name
            };
GrdWork.DataSource = query.ToList();
GrdWorkPub.DataBind();
```

I haven't tried the code out, so there may be minor syntatic changes, but essentially what it's doing is:

1. Use LINQ to get a collection of a new anonymous type that has one entry per row with the id and name from the table.  You have to use AsEnumerable() [contained in System.Data.DataSetExtensions].
2. Convert the LINQ result set to a List via .ToList() and bind it to the GridView.

If you can post a little more information - what exactly you mean by display, and the expected shape of the returned DataTable (i.e., what the columns in each row are) we can give you a better answer.

**UPDATE**
If you're storing the XML document above in your datastore and that is being returned in the table, try this code:

```
DataTable FBWorkDt = objBLL.get_FacebookWork(FacebookUserId);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(FBWorkDt.Rows[0][0].ToString());

var query = from x in xDoc.Descendants("employer")
            select new 
            {
                id = (string)x.Element("id"),
                name = (string)x.Element("name")
            }
GrdWork.DataSource = query.ToList();
GrdWorkPub.DataBind();
```

Same basic principal as above, except this time your querying over an XDocument instead of a DataTable.

Comment: When I go for the first approach, I modified the syntax a little var query = from x in FBWorkDt.AsEnumerable()
                        select new
                        {
                            id = x.Field<int>("id"),
                            name = x.Field<string>("name")
                        }; But here it says id, name are not found in the table

Comment: What are the column names in the DataTable?  It looks like, based on the code you posted in your question, that you're inserting the XML document in one column and an id in another column.  If you are indeed storing the whole XML in a column in the DataTable, you'll find the second way easier.